# strtok gives first element few times

Tags: c, strtok

When I using `strtok(str, " ");` with the space delimiting character, and when I try to print all strings in the line of string, it gives me my first string few times.

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void usage();
void morseText(char);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char * pch; 
    if(argc != 3)
        usage();
    else {
        if(strcmp(argv[1],"-m") == 0){
            for(int i=0; i<strlen(argv[2]); i++){
                pch = strtok(argv[2], " ,");
                while (pch != NULL){
                    printf("%s\n", pch);
                    pch = strtok(NULL, " ,");
                    }
                }
            printf("morse to text\n");
        }
        else if(strcmp(argv[1], "-t") == 0){
            printf("text to morse:\n");
            for(int i=0; i<strlen(argv[2]); i++){
                morseText(argv[2][i]);
                }
            printf("\n");
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
void morseText(char a){
    if(a>=97)
        a = a - 32;
    if(a == 'A')
        printf(".-");
    else if(a == 'B')
        printf("-...");     
    else if(a == 'C')
        printf("-.-.");
    else if(a == 'D')
        printf("-..");
    else if(a == 'E')
        printf(".");
    else if(a =='F')
        printf("..-.");
    else if(a =='G')
        printf("--.");
    else if(a == 'H')
        printf("....");
    else if(a == 'I')
        printf("..");
    else if(a == 'J')
        printf(".---");
    else if(a == 'K')
        printf("-.-");
    else if(a == 'L')
        printf(".-..");
    else if(a == 'M')
        printf("--");
    else if(a == 'N')
        printf("-.");
    else if(a == 'O')
        printf("---");
    else if(a == 'P')
        printf(".--.");
    else if(a == 'Q')
        printf("--.-");
    else if(a == 'R')
        printf(".-.");
    else if(a == 'S')
        printf("...");
    else if(a == 'T')
        printf("-");
    else if(a == 'U')
        printf("..-");
    else if(a == 'V')
        printf("...-");
    else if(a == 'W')
        printf(".--");
    else if(a == 'X')
        printf("-..-");
    else if(a == 'Y')
        printf("-.--");
    else if(a == 'Z')
        printf("--..");
    else if(a == '0')
        printf("-----");
    else if(a == '1')
        printf(".----");
    else if(a == '2')
        printf("..---");
    else if(a == '3')
        printf("...--");
    else if(a == '4')
        printf("....-");
    else if(a == '5')
        printf(".....");
    else if(a == '6')
        printf("-....");
    else if(a == '7')
        printf("--...");
    else if(a == '8')
        printf("---..");
    else if(a =='9')
        printf("----.");
    else if(a == 32)
        printf(" ");
    else if(a == 13)
        printf("\n");
    else
        printf("Not applicable char\n");
}

void usage(){
    printf("Usage: ./morse -o string\n");
    printf("-o could be \"-m\" from morse to text\n");
    printf("-o could be \"-t\" from text to morse\n");
    printf("string could be file input or direct text input\n");
    printf("for example: ./morse -m \"--.\"\n");
    printf("\t or  ./morse -t \"aab\"\n");
}
```

I am trying to write simple morse converter. Just curiosity. But I do not understand why it is printing more of my first arguments few times. 
The result is following 
[The compiled code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEa2I.png)

I am waiting for only 4 result since I provided `"... .... .... ---..--"` that result. 
But the code gives me

```
...
....
....
---..--
...
...
```

this result.

Does anyone knows why is it working this way?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you forget about this loop: `for(int i=0; i<strlen(argv[2]); i++)`?

Comment: BTW: `strtok(argv[2], " ,");` alters `argv[2]`; Not sure about that, but I feel that altering a command line argument is "not supported" (UB?)

Comment: @StephanLechner on the contrary, it is perfectly valid to modify them

Comment: *"The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to by the argv array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program startup and program termination."*

Comment: @Antti Haapala: thanks!

Comment: Yes I forgot about the for(int i=0; i<strlen(argv[2]); i++) this loop, except this section, everything works fine :) thanks

Comment: Unrelated, but you should seriously think about a more elegant implementation of the `morseText` function.

Comment: Consider using `a = toupper( a ) ;` and a `switch` or a look-up table rather then `if-else if...` for `morseText`.  To decode `Z` for example, 26 comparisons are made, while for `A` it makes just one.  Perhaps not a serious problem in this case, but for larger associative-maps to solve similar problems, or where deterministic and constant timing is required it could be an issue.